# remove "index.php?" from htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have code in htaccess that strips "index.php" but not the "?"
Here's what I have

```
# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

I also tried this but caused more problems:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/index\.php\?\/(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$  /%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^index\.php$  /index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Sorry if I was not clear. I'll try again. There are some old links out there that are like the following: `example.com/index.php?/destinations/denali-state-park`. I am wanting to remove any occurrence of `index.php?` from the URL so `.htaccess` would redirect the above URL to this: `example.com/destinations/denali-state-park`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. This reads like a classical X/Y problem. As if you are trying to ask how you can do something that you suspect might solve your actual issue. Don't. Instead ask how to solve your actual issue.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer as your question is not clear and what I supposed you meant isn't really the question. You should clarify your question with what exactly you want to achieve. Give examples of the URLs your users will access and the rewrite results you want, so we can then help you more effectively.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I'll try again.

There are some old links out there that are like the following:

https://www.trekalaska.com/index.php?/destinations/denali-state-park

I am wanting to remove any occurance of "index.php?" from the url

So htaccess would redirct the above URL to this...

https://www.trekalaska.com/destinations/denali-state-park

Comment: @GregFensterman You need to **edit your question** to add that additional information.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry if I was not clear. I'll try again. There are some old links out there that are like the following: `example.com/index.php?/destinations/denali-state-park`. I am wanting to remove any occurance of `index.php?` from the URL So `.htaccess` would redirect the above URL to this... `example.com/destinations/denali-state-park`

From your example, you need to remove `index.php?/`, not just `index.php?`.

The `?` delimits the start of the query string, so it's not just a case of removing `index.php` from the URL-path, you need to *move* the query string (that looks like a URL-path) into the URL-path part of the URL (and remove the original query string).

You can do that using the following rule at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect URLs of the form "/index.php?/<url>" to "/<url>"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(/[\w/-]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1 [QSD,NE,R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path `index.php` only. The preceding *condition* then matches a query string that looks-like a URL-path (ie. starts with a slash and contains only alphanumeric chars, slashes and hyphens) - this is *captured* and used directly in the new *substitution* string using the `%1` backreference (that includes the slash prefix).

The `QSD` flag ensures that the "old" query string (that contained the URL-path) is discarded from the redirected response. The `NE` flag prevents the *substitution* being URL-encoded, since the captured query string is already URL-encoded (thus preventing it being doubly-URL-encoded).

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. And make sure your browser cache is cleared before testing.

#### Additional notes:

- This rule is in addition to any rule that might simply remove `index.php` from the URL-path (if that is still required). However, this rule must come first.
- I'm assuming you have a front-controller pattern later in the file that internally rewrites the request back to `index.php` (in some way other than a query string**<sup>*1</sup>**, which would result in a rewrite loop!), otherwise you are simply going to get a 404 when implementing the above rule by itself.

  **<sup>*1</sup>** If you are rewriting back to `index.php` *with a query string* then you will need an additional *condition* on the rule above to prevent a rewrite loop (500 Internal Server Error):

  ```
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  :
  ```

---

**A quick look at your rules...**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
> ```

Yes, this only removes `index.php` (or `index.php/`) from the URL-path, preserving the original query string. Based on your example URL, this does *more* than is needed, since `index.php` always appears to be in the root of the URL-path and your URLs don't contain path-info (or do they)?

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/index\.php\?\/(.*)\sHTTP.*$
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$  /%1? [L,R=301]
> RewriteRule !^index\.php$  /index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
> ```

The first rule here looks to be effectively the same as what I'm doing in the rule above and "should work". The `%1` backreference contains the query string (less the slash prefix) and the trailing `?` on the *substitution* string effectively removes the original query string (similar to the `QSD` flag on later versions of Apache).

However, the "problem" is likely the 2nd rule (effectively the front-controller pattern) that *unconditionally* rewrites the request back to `/index.php`, passing the requested URL-path as a query string again. (As I mentioned above, I'm assuming your application is not expecting the URL-path to be passed in the query string.) This also has the (possibly) undesirable effect of rewriting all your static assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.) and passing these to your front-controller (`index.php`).